# MySQL Prepare Statement returning Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

atempting to run this in a H2 MySQL console.

```
SET @temp = 'constraintName';
SELECT @temp;
SET @string = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE MESSAGE DROP foreign key ', @temp);
SELECT @string;
PREPARE stmt1 From @string;
```

Temp and string print correctly with the expected values.
Runing these comands returns this error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "PREPARE STMT1 FROM[*] @STRING"; expected "(, AS"; SQL statement:
PREPARE stmt1 From @string [42001-200] 42001/42001 (Help)
```

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: maybe try changing to this ```SET @string = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE MESSAGE AS DROP foreign key ', @temp);```

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion, but got the same error @fthomson

Comment: does the query stored in ```@string``` work outside of the ```PREPARE``` statement?

Comment: Can you please run `SELECT VERSION() FROM dual;` and `SELECT H2VERSION() FROM dual;` and report the result?

Comment: I suspect you are using H2, not MySQL. These are two different products that each support different SQL syntax. You seem to be using MySQL syntax.

Comment: You tagged the question with "mysql" and "h2". Please use only the tag of the database your question is relatet to.

Comment: Its meant to be a H2 using a MY SQL driver...
Select H2VERSION:
```1.4.200```
Select Version:
```Function "VERSION" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT VERSION() FROM dual [90022-200] 90022/90022 (Help)```